# How to save dynamically added div elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This function add new div dynamically:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  i = '1';
  x = '0';

  $("#btn3").click(function() {
    i++;
    x++;

    z = x * 2;
    r = z + 1;

    $('<div class="mainContainer"><div class="relayBlock"><span class="relayTitle">Obwód ' + i + ' </span> <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" type="button" id=' + z + ' onClick="relayClick(this.id)">Wł</button> <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-danger" type="button" id=' + r + ' onClick="relayClick(this.id)">Wył</button></div></div>').appendTo("#container");
  });
});
```

How can I save the new created "div" ? New "div" must be visible after refreshing page.

Comment: Why `i` and `x` are strings while they are needed as numbers?

Comment: Not doable, unless you dynamically create a page via the server and store the div info into the server's sources

Comment: Execute this javascript everytime the page is loaded. But if you want to save it after each click, then you need to store this progress on DB or server, one way or another.

Comment: Try using the browser [local storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to store the div when you create them and to gather the div after reloading the page to set the previous state,

Comment: @CatalinIancu I want to store progress on server, but I don't know how do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You can save your `html` content with `localStorage`:*

**Save:**

```
  var html = $('#container').html();
  window.localStorage.setItem('content',html);
```

**Read:**

```
$('#container').html(window.localStorage.getItem('content'));
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9j9yqc2q/2/)

*And if you want to empty `localStorage` go with this:*

```
window.localStorage.removeItem('content');
```

**Or**

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9j9yqc2q/3/)**

Comment: It works, but I want the code created dynamically to be added to the html code of the page.

Comment: @Daro125 What you mean? it already added to your saved content.

Comment: Ok, but what if I open this page on the other device?

Comment: @Daro125 It's cross browser and cross platform, works on all device.

Comment: I tried on two devices (the files I have on the local server) and on each I had to add a new one.

Comment: @Daro125 each device has own `localStorage` you can't access a device saved data, in other device. in this case you should insert into DataBase.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  i = '1';
  x = '0';

  $("#btn3").click(function() {
    i++;
    x++;

    z = x * 2;
    r = z + 1;

    $("#container").append('<div class="mainContainer"><div class="relayBlock"><span class="relayTitle">Obwód ' + i + ' </span> <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" type="button" id=' + z + ' onClick="relayClick(this.id)">Wł</button> <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-danger" type="button" id=' + r + ' onClick="relayClick(this.id)">Wył</button></div></div>');
  });
});
```

need to change which is appending element

Comment: It doesn't change anything.